# Output not in readable format in Spark 2.2.0 Dataset

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-dataset, apache-spark-2.0

Following is the code which i am trying to execute with spark2.2.0 on intellij IDE. But the output i am getting is doesnt look in readble format.

```
val spark = SparkSession
      .builder()
      .appName("Spark SQL basic example").master("local[2]")
      .getOrCreate()

    // For implicit conversions like converting RDDs to DataFrames
    import spark.implicits._

    import scala.reflect.ClassTag
    implicit def kryoEncoder[A](implicit ct: ClassTag[A]) =
      org.apache.spark.sql.Encoders.kryo[A](ct)

    case class Person(name: String, age: Long)

    // Encoders are created for case classes
    val caseClassDS = Seq(Person("Andy", 32)).toDS()
    caseClassDS.show()
```

Output shown :

```
+--------------------+
|               value|
+--------------------+
|[01 00 44 61 74 6...|
+--------------------+
```

Can anyone explain if I am missing anything here?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is because you're using Kryo `Encoder` which is not designed to deserialize objects for `show`.

In general you should never use Kryo `Encoder` when more precise `Encoders` are available. It has poorer performance and less features. Instead use `Product` `Encoder`

```
spark.createDataset(Seq(Person("Andy", 32)))(Encoders.product[Person])
```

Comment: Thanks, But this doesnt seems to work for me. Adding 
 val caseClassDS = spark.createDataset(Seq(Person("Andy", 32)))(Encoders.product[Person])   into my code is giving exception :

Comment: Thanks, But this doesnt seems to work for me. Adding 
 val caseClassDS = spark.createDataset(Seq(Person("Andy", 32)))(Encoders.product[Person])   into my code is giving exception :

Error:(24, 84) No TypeTag available for Person
    val caseClassDS = spark.createDataset(Seq(Person("Andy", 32)))(Encoders.product[Person])

Comment: Can you remove `implicit` from `implicit def kryoEncoder[` and start over? Or remove `implicit def kryoEncoder` completely.